# Access denied for user 'root@localhost' (using password:NO)

Tags: mysql, wordpress, mysql-error-1045

I'm trying to run WordPress in my Windows desktop and it needs MySQL.

I install everything with `Web Platform Installer` which is provided by Microsoft. I never set a root password for MySQL and in the final step of installing WordPress, it asks for a MySQL server password.

What is the default password for root (if there is one) and how to change it?

I tried:

```
mysql -u root password '123'
```

But it shows me:

```
Access denied for user 'root@localhost' (using password:NO)
```

After this I try:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

However, it asks for a password which I don't have.

---

**Update**: as Bozho suggested, I did the following:

1. I stopped the MySQL Service from Windows services
2. Opened CMD
3. Changed the location to c:\program files\mysql\bin
4. Executed the command below

   `mysqld --defaults-file="C:\\program files\\mysql\\mysql server 5.1\\my.ini" --init-files=C:\\root.txt`
5. The command ran with a warning about character set which I mentioned below
6. I start the MySQL service from Windows services
7. I write in the command line

   `mysql -u root -p`
   `EnterPassword: 123  // 123 was the password`
8. The command line shows the following error

   `Access denied for user 'root@localhost' (using password:**YES**)`

How do I solve this?

Comment: The first command is wrong, should be `-p` or `--password`, but not `password`. That's why mysql responds with USING PASSWORD NO.

Comment: Nobody seems to have given him the obvious answer. The password for the `root` userid is **blank** after the initial install. So just do `mysql -u root -p` and then just hit enter, i.e. leave the password blank. Then of course put a password on the `root` userid.

Comment: @RiggsFolly nope, doesn't work! blank password gives me access denied!

Comment: I want add a comment as I am not sure the accepted answer is the correct one. For me typing mysql -u root -p and then once prompt for the password, give the right one(the one set at installation) worked. Instead proving the name of a DB to the  -p with a DB I know exist did not worked.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You can [reset your root password](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/resetting-permissions.html). Have in mind that it is not advisable to use root without password.

Comment: @Bozho - I follow the instruction aand create a text file and call it from the mentioned command, after that I face with `100608 [warning] --default-character-set is deprecated and will be removed in a future release. please use --character-set-server instead` .-------------------------------- and finally when I start my mysql service again I face withthe exact error but this time with `(using password:yes)` what should I do?

Comment: @Bozo - Note that I couldn't run your command with `mysqldt-nt` I run it by `mysqldt -nt` Actuallythe first one is not recognizable for cmd. I'm waiting to hear from you.

Comment: @Bozho - I've update my question with the bug. thank you for your time.

Comment: @Bozho - is there a way to update / customise my mysql errors? **Update "Access denied for user 'root@localhost' (using password:NO)"
 to "Access denied for user 'myname@localhost' (using password:NO)" **

Answer (score 126):

for this kind of error; you just have to set new password to the root user as an admin. follow the steps as follows:

```
[root ~]# mysql -u root
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password:NO)
```

1. Stop the service/daemon of mysql running

   ```
    [root ~]# service mysql stop   
    mysql stop/waiting
   ```
2. Start mysql without any privileges using the following option;
   This option is used to boot up and do not use the privilege system of MySQL.

   ```
    [root ~]# mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
   ```

**At this moment, the terminal will seem to halt**. Let that be, and use new terminal for next steps.

3. enter the mysql command prompt

   ```
    [root ~]# mysql -u root
    mysql>
   ```
4. Fix the permission setting of the root user ;

   ```
    mysql> use mysql;
    Database changed
    mysql> select * from  user;
    Empty set (0.00 sec)
    mysql> truncate table user;
    Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
    mysql> flush privileges;
    Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
    mysql> grant all privileges on *.* to root@localhost identified by 'YourNewPassword' with grant option;
    Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)
   ```

*if you don`t want any password or rather an empty password

```
    mysql> grant all privileges on *.* to root@localhost identified by '' with grant option;
    Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.01 sec)*
    mysql> flush privileges;
    Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Confirm the results:

```
    mysql> select host, user from user;
+-----------+------+
| host      | user |
+-----------+------+
| localhost | root |
+-----------+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

5. Exit the shell and restart mysql in normal mode.

   ```
    mysql> quit;
    [root ~]# kill -KILL [PID of mysqld_safe]
    [root ~]# kill -KILL [PID of mysqld]
    [root ~]# service mysql start
   ```
6. Now you can successfully login as root user with the password you set

   ```
     [root ~]# mysql -u root -pYourNewPassword 
     mysql>
   ```

Comment: Press Enter after "[root ~]# mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &" and open another terminal to enter "[root ~]# mysql -u root"

Comment: i met this problem, and i did alot, just forget restarting the db services... many thanks!

Comment: At step 3, I get `ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)`

Comment: @MrMartin, create that dir ```sudo mkdir -p /var/run/mysqld``` and give permission to it ```sudo chown mysql:mysql /var/run/mysqld```

Comment: this is the answer that helped me a lot!

Comment: `SELECT * from user;` gives a non-empty table.  So I have to skip truncating the table, then `grant all privileges on *.* to root@localhost ...` gives an error: `The MySQL server is running with the --skip-grant-tables option so it cannot execute this statement`. How to solve this?

Comment: There should be a warning that `truncate table user;` will delete all the users, subsequently the command `grant all privileges on *.* to root@localhost identified by 'YourNewPassword' with grant option;` doesn't work because the root user hasn't been recreated

Comment: I got `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'identified by 'password' with grant option' at line 1` after run `grant all privileges on *.* to root@localhost identified by '' with grant option;`

Answer (score 33):

Use mysql -u root -p 
It will ask for password, insert password and enter.

Comment: This worked after I was getting Access denied for users.

Comment: This worked when all of the above did not. (Mac os big sur, fresh install of MySQL 8)

Answer (score 27):

1) You can set root password by invoking MySQL console. It is located in

`C:\wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.1.53\bin` by default.

Get to the directory and type MySQL. then set the password as follows..

```
    > SET PASSWORD FOR root@localhost = PASSWORD('new-password');
```

2) You can configure wamp's phpmyadmin application for root user by editing

```
C:\wamp\apps\phpmyadmin3.3.9\config.inc.php
```

**Note :-** if you are using xampp then , file will be located at

```
C:\xampp\phpMyadmin\config.inc.php
```

It looks like this:

```
        $cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'localhost';
        $cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
        $cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '';
        $cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = '';
        $cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
        $cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
        $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
        $cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
        $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'YOURPASSWORD';
        $cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;
```

The error "Access denied for user 'root@localhost' (using password:NO)"
will be resolved when you set `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword']` to  **false**

If you priviously changed the password for 'root@localhost', then you have to do 2 things to solve the error "Access denided for user 'root@localhost'":

1. if ['password'] have a empty quotes like **' '** then put your password between quotes.
2. change the (using password:NO) to (using password:YES)

This will resolve the error.

Note: phpmyadmin is a separate tool which comes with wamp. 
It just provide a interface to MySQL. if you change my sql root's password, then you should change the phpmyadmin configurations. Usually phpmyadmin is configured to root user.

Comment: no you cant.. mysql will not start: c:\wamp64\bin\mysql\mysql5.7.23\bin>mysql
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'ODBC'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Comment: Worked for me! Thank you Andreas! :  )

Answer (score 13):

I was getting the same error on OS X El captain. 
Mysql version 5.7 . I was able to connect to mysql with root after executing these steps.

Stop the mysql server

```
sudo mysql.server stop
```

Start mysql in safe mode

```
sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
```

Using mysqld, Change the database to mysql and update the details for user 'root'.

```
show databases;
use mysql;
UPDATE mysql.user 
    SET authentication_string = PASSWORD('MyNewPass'), password_expired = 'N'
    WHERE User = 'root' AND Host = 'localhost';
exit;
```

After that kill the 'mysqld_safe' process and start mysql normally. You should be able to login to mysql using root and new password. [SQL docs for more details](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html)

Answer (score 11):

Simply edit `my.ini` file in C:\xampp\mysql\bin path. Just add:

```
skip-grant-tables
```

line in between lines of `# The MySQL server [mysqld]` and `port=3306`. Then restart the MySQL server.

Looks like:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: When I do this I get another error `communications link failure`

Answer (score 8):

For some information I've get error after changing password:

> Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
>
> Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

In both cases there was error.

But the thing is after that I've tried it with

`mysql -uroot -ppassword` instead of

`mysql -u root -p password` -> with spaces between -uroot and -ppassword so maybe if someone get trouble can try this way.

Answer (score 6):

Make sure the MySQL service is running on your machine, then follow the instructions from MySQL for initially setting up root (search for 'windows' and it will take you to the steps for setting up root):

[Securing the Initial MySQL Account](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/default-privileges.html)

Comment: This solution wont work for me because i don't have the password which it need in second step.

Comment: This is what I was looking at when I sent the link, are you sure this doesn't work?  I don't see any reference to the old password.

For Windows, do this:

shell> mysql -u root
mysql> SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('newpwd');
mysql> SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'127.0.0.1' = PASSWORD('newpwd');
mysql> SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'%' = PASSWORD('newpwd');

Comment: As I told before when I write `mysql -u root` I face with problem and I can not login to mysql to run second line. so How to use this command?

Answer (score 5):

Another solution if someone gets the error *The specified password for user account ‘root’ is not valid, or failed to connect to the database server* also with the right password, is the follow

•In the Windows registry, delete the mysql_pwd reg key under HKCU\Software\Microsoft\WebPlatformInstaller

•Unistall older version of MySQL .NET connector

•Download and install the latest [MySql .NET Connector](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/).

Comment: Checking password and database name worked for me.. +1

Answer (score 5):

1. Change the password from `config.inc.php` present in `C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin`.
2. Type `mysql -u root -p` in the command prompt.
3. You will be asked to enter the password. Enter that password which you updated in the `config.inc.php`.

Comment: I needn't update password. The `-p` param solved everything

Answer (score 4):

In your code replace the **'root'** with your Server **username** and password with your server password.
For example if you have DB and your php files on the server http://www.example.com
then obviously you would have to enter into this server site using your username and password.

Answer (score 4):

For MySQL 5.7. These are the below steps:

Stop your MySQL server completely. This can be done by accessing the Services window inside Windows XP and Windows Server 2003, where you can stop the MySQL service.

Open your MS-DOS command prompt using "cmd" inside the Run window. Inside it navigate to your MySQL bin folder, such as C:\MySQL\bin using the cd command.

Execute the following command in the command prompt: mysqld.exe -u root --skip-grant-tables

Leave the current MS-DOS command prompt as it is, and open a new MS-DOS command prompt window.

Navigate to your MySQL bin folder, such as C:\MySQL\bin using the cd command.

Enter mysql and press enter.

You should now have the MySQL command prompt working. Type use mysql; so that we switch to the "mysql" database.

Execute the following command to update the password:

update user set authentication_string=password('1111') where user='root';

Answer (score 3):

Some times it just happens due to installation of Wamp or changing of password options of root user.
One can use privilages-->root (user) and then set password option to NO to run the things without any password OR set the password and use it in the application.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using XAMPP just go to `C:\xampp\phpMyAdmin` and then open `config.inc.php` find `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = ''` line and put your password there.

Answer (score 3):

if you changed the port to non standard one, then you need to specify it:

```
$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost:3308', 'root', '', 'loginapp');
```

Answer (score 1):

It happens because of the security reason.

try with the following

```
mysql -u root -p
```

click enter and enter the password and try again

Answer (score 1):

If the root account exists but has no password, connect to the server as root using no password, then assign a password. This was my situation when I encountered this issue.

Connect to the server as root using no password:

```
$> mysql -u root --skip-password
```

Assign a password:

```
mysql> ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'root-password';
```

I was able to solve my problem this way. Hope this helps someone who encounters a similar issue in the future. Cheers!

Reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/default-privileges.html

Answer (score 0):

This means that the user has no access. This can be fixed in the following ways

**make sure the host is set to ´%´**

```
 insert into mysql.user (Host, User, Password) VALUES ('%', 'root', password('setyourpasswordhere'));
    GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

or if you are using SQL workbench, you can create an user under

Administration  --> users and privileges --> click on Add account button and create a new user, with hosts as **%** and grant the privileges in Administrative roles, schema privileges tabs.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

```
mysqladmin -u root -p password
```

enter your `current` `password`

then

enter your `new password`

Comment: The whole point is that the OP _doesn't know_ the current password, because _it was never set_.

Comment: I knew my password but had issue with login with temp password. this answer worked for me