# Access Denied for User 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) - No Privileges?

Tags: mysql, root, mysql-workbench, workbench

I am continuously receiving this error.

I am using mySQL Workbench and from what I am finding is that root's schema privileges are null. There are no privileges at all.

I am having troubles across platforms that my server is used for and this has been all of a sudden issue.

**root@127.0.0.1** apparently has a lot of access but I am logged in as that, but it just assigns to localhost anyways - localhost has no privileges.

I have done a few things like `FLUSH HOSTS`, `FLUSH PRIVILEGES`, etc
but have found no success from that or the internet.

How can I get root its access back? I find this frustrating because when I look around people expect you to "have access" but I don't have access so I can't go into command line or anything and `GRANT` myself anything.

When running `SHOW GRANTS FOR root` this is what I get in return:

> Error Code: 1141. There is no such grant defined for user 'root' on
>   host '%'

Comment: Run `SHOW GRANTS FOR root` in a query, post the result in your question.

Comment: You're trying to access the database from the localhost or from another host using MySQL Workbench?

Comment: restart server with --skip-grant-table and login with any user and provide full privileges to root and restart server again without the above option

Comment: @AndyJones no, it's on a dedicated server I am using.

Comment: @vidyadhar I'm sorry, I'm not sure where I would do that?

Comment: The problem is not a forgotten password, but all the privileges are set to localhost and you're trying to access the database from another machine (NOT local host)?

Comment: @AndyJones I'm sorry Andy, to be more clear, I am accessing workbench/the sql server from the server. I run mysqld on a dedicated server which also allows me to connect to it; like an actual computer. 
That said, I am localhost. 

Not a forgotten password, and there is a password. Also, the privileges claim to be set to 127.0.0.1 but it forces me back to localhost.

http://prntscr.com/1ilmnj - while it's connecting to 127.0.0.1 it masks me for the privileges of localhost, which doesn't have GRANT options.

Comment: For me i was using MYSQLWorkbench and the port was 3306 MAMP using 8889

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Use [the instructions for resetting the root password](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html) - but instead of resetting the root password, we'll going to forcefully INSERT a record into the mysql.user table

In the init file, use this instead

```
INSERT INTO mysql.user (Host, User, Password) VALUES ('%', 'root', password('YOURPASSWORD'));
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Comment: I'm sorry Andy, but when I get to step 6 I keep running into a problem. Since I did use an installation wizard, I would be using
`"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysqld.exe"
         --defaults-file="C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.6\\my.ini"
         --init-file=C:\\mysql-init.txt`

Everything is where it is supposed to be and what you have above I did put in the file accordingly. I do have the service stopped as well.

I just get this output: http://prntscr.com/1ilxau

And everything (plugins) shutdown. Really confusing.

Comment: are you running this as an administrator?

Comment: At my stupidity surprise, I wasn't. After I was, I got this http://prntscr.com/1imcnj - The first time I did it on their own lines (from paste) then I put it all on one line.
I'm sorry this is just so confusing for me, not the sql expert per se.

Comment: it give: `ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'Password' in 'field list'` error. @AndyJones

Comment: I am getting : Unknown column 'Password' in 'field list'

Comment: @AndyJones Use "Authentication_string" instead of password

Comment: Even if you change it to `authentication_string`, it will result in `ERROR 1364 (HY000): Field 'ssl_cipher' doesn't have a default value`.

Comment: I am trying to connect to docker mysql container from Dbeaver but getting the error "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)" . Can someone please suggest some solution ?

Comment: Error Code: 1227. Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation

Answer (score 276):

If you have that same problem in MySql 5.7.+ :

```
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
```

it's because MySql 5.7 by default allow to connect with socket, which means you just connect with `sudo mysql`. If you run sql :

```
SELECT user,authentication_string,plugin,host FROM mysql.user;
```

then you will see it :

```
+------------------+-------------------------------------------+-----------------------+-----------+
| user             | authentication_string                     | plugin                | host      |
+------------------+-------------------------------------------+-----------------------+-----------+
| root             |                                           | auth_socket           | localhost |
| mysql.session    | *THISISNOTAVALIDPASSWORDTHATCANBEUSEDHERE | mysql_native_password | localhost |
| mysql.sys        | *THISISNOTAVALIDPASSWORDTHATCANBEUSEDHERE | mysql_native_password | localhost |
| debian-sys-maint | *497C3D7B50479A812B89CD12EC3EDA6C0CB686F0 | mysql_native_password | localhost |
+------------------+-------------------------------------------+-----------------------+-----------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

To allow connection with root and password, then update the values in the table with command :

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'Current-Root-Password';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Then run the select command again and you'll see it has changed :

```
+------------------+-------------------------------------------+-----------------------+-----------+
| user             | authentication_string                     | plugin                | host      |
+------------------+-------------------------------------------+-----------------------+-----------+
| root             | *2F2377C1BC54BE827DC8A4EE051CBD57490FB8C6 | mysql_native_password | localhost |
| mysql.session    | *THISISNOTAVALIDPASSWORDTHATCANBEUSEDHERE | mysql_native_password | localhost |
| mysql.sys        | *THISISNOTAVALIDPASSWORDTHATCANBEUSEDHERE | mysql_native_password | localhost |
| debian-sys-maint | *497C3D7B50479A812B89CD12EC3EDA6C0CB686F0 | mysql_native_password | localhost |
+------------------+-------------------------------------------+-----------------------+-----------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

And that's it. You can run this process after running and completing the `sudo mysql_secure_installation` command.

For mariadb, use

```
SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('manager');
```

to set password.
More at https://mariadb.com/kb/en/set-password/

Comment: Really Thanks while connection Establishment in linux mint

Comment: Updating from `auth_socket` to `mysql_native_password` fixed my problem. Thank you!

Comment: This was absolutely infuriating trying to figure out and a giant waste of time. I wish they asked this during `mysql_secure_installation`. Thank you so much for this answer.

Comment: this was also helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2995054/access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-passwordno

Comment: I did this but and the table entry changed the same way but password still not working. Also, `sudo mysql_secure_installation` prompts for password too.

Comment: @mr.loop , this was in the case on fresh installation, where mysql prioritize socket auth over old password prompt. In your case I don't really know about your mysql instance. You might have to reset your password if any.

Comment: Error Code: 1221. Incorrect usage of ALTER and SYSTEM USER

Comment: @cmcodes, this might be user permission issue if installation is not fresh. Check the user privileges.

Comment: Thanks , it worked for me.. ```ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'Current-Root-Password';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;```

Comment: ERROR 1142 (42000): SELECT command denied to user ''@'localhost' for table `mysql`.`user`. 
This issue occurs with mariadb installation

Answer (score 64):

It didn't like my user privilege so I SUDO it.
(in bash << sudo set user and password)
(this gives username of root and sets the password to nothing)
(On Mac)

```
sudo mysql -uroot -p
```

Comment: Perfect! This solution works for Ubuntu 20.04 LTS, too.

Answer (score 35):

Try the following commands

```
~$ sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
~$ sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
~$ mysql -u root
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.

Your MySQL connection id is 1 to server version: 4.1.15-Debian_1-log

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the buffer.

mysql>

mysql> use mysql;

mysql> update user set password=PASSWORD("root") where User='root';

mysql> flush privileges;

mysql> quit

~$ sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop

Stopping MySQL database server: mysqld

STOPPING server from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid

mysqld_safe[6186]: ended

[1]+  Done                    mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables

~$ sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start

~$ mysql -u root -p

* MySQL Community Server 5.6.35 is started
~$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 1
Server version: 5.6.35 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2016, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql>
```

Comment: In MySQL 5.7, the password field in mysql.user table field was removed, now the field name is 'authentication_string'.

Comment: for newer version of mysql they changed the password column name as authentication_string

Comment: `sudo mysqld_safe` got me this `/var/run/mysqld for UNIX socket file don't exists`, then after `mkdir -p /var/run/mysqld` and `sudo chown -R mysql:mysql /var/run/mysqld/` it worked and started the daemon.

Comment: ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.so

Comment: For Mysql 8+ on Systemd distros (maybe also for Mysql 5.7 whether Centos  Rocky or Ubuntu), when you are stuck with the mysqld_safe running and cannot stop it using `sudo /etc/init/d/mysql stop` instead run as root `# mysqladmin shutdown`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/53086515

Answer (score 28):

for the people who are facing below error in mysql 5.7+ version -

```
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

1. Open new terminal
2. `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop`
   ...
   MySQL Community Server 5.7.8-rc is stopped
3. `sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &`
   this will skipp all grant level privileges and start the mysql in safe mode
   Sometimes the process got stucked just because of

grep: write error: Broken pipe
180102 11:32:28 mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mysql/error.log'.

Simply press Ctrl+Z or Ctrl+C to interrupt and exit process

4. `mysql -u root`

Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 2
Server version: 5.7.8-rc MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2015, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

5. mysql> `use mysql;`

Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Database changed

6. mysql> `update user set authentication_string=password('password') where user='root';`
   Query OK, 4 rows affected, 1 warning (0.03 sec)
   Rows matched: 4  Changed: 4  Warnings: 1
7. mysql> `flush privileges;`
   Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
8. mysql> `quit`
   Bye
9. `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop`

..180102 11:37:12 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid ended
.
 * MySQL Community Server 5.7.8-rc is stopped
arif@ubuntu:~$ sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start
..
 * MySQL Community Server 5.7.8-rc is started

10. `mysql -u root -p`

    Enter password:

    Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
    Your MySQL connection id is 2
    Server version: 5.7.8-rc MySQL Community Server (GPL)

after mysql 5.7+ version the column password replaced by name authentication_string from the mysql.user table.

hope these steps will help anyone, thanks.

Answer (score 19):

I was using ubuntu 18 and simply installed MySQL (password:root) with the following commands.

```
sudo apt install mysql-server
sudo mysql_secure_installation
```

When I tried to log in with the normal ubuntu user it was throwing me this issue.

```
ERROR 1698 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
```

But I was able to login to MySQL via the super user. Using the following commands I was able to log in via a normal user.

```
sudo mysql    
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'root';
exit;
```

Then you should be able to login to Mysql with the normal account.

[image]

Answer (score 19):

**If you are getting this error in Workbench but you are able to log in from terminal then follow this steps.**

First simply log in with your current password:

```
sudo mysql -u root -p
```

Then change your password because having low strength password gives error sometimes.

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'new-strong-password';

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Then simply exit and again login with your new password:

```
quit

sudo mysql -u root -p
```

Once you successfully logged in type the command:

```
use mysql;
```

It should show a message like 'Database changed' then type:

```
UPDATE user SET plugin='mysql_native_password' WHERE User='root';
```

After that type:

```
UPDATE mysql.user set authentication_string=PASSWORD('new-strong-password') where user='root';
```

Then type:

```
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Then simply exit:

```
quit
```

Now try to log in with your new password in your WORKBENCH. Hope it will work. Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

A simple way to reset root password on Linux systems :

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure mysql-server-5.5
```

Checkout some other reasons for Access denied :

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/problems-connecting.html

Comment: find your version with "locate mysql-server", and run the command accordingly

Answer (score 6):

For my case, I found this error after fresh installation of mysql on Mac OS Big Sur.

What i did to fix it was:
I click on the apple logo, go to system preferences and then click on mysql.

There's an initialize database button on the opened settings window, I click on that, and then when I try to access again, it's solved.

Comment: Yes, work like a champ if you install it through - https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/

Comment: Thanks Sitti. I get what you are saying. It's sad/confusing you have to interact with this UI first :(

Answer (score 5):

I faced this problem while installing Testlink on Ubuntu server, I followed these steps

```
mysql -u root
use mysql;
update user set password=PASSWORD("root") where User='root';
flush privileges;
quit
```

Now stop the instance and start again i.e

```
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql stop
sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start
```

Answer (score 3):

in mysql 5.7 the password field has been replaced with authentication_string so you would do something like this instead

```
update user set authentication_string=PASSWORD("root") where User='root';
```

See this link [MySQL user DB does not have password columns - Installing MySQL on OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30692812/mysql-user-db-does-not-have-password-columns-installing-mysql-on-osx)

Answer (score 3):

```
alter user 'root'@'localhost' identified with mysql_native_password by '$your_password$';
```

it worked for me.

note: use strong password

**for exampl**e

```
alter user 'root'@'localhost' identified with mysql_native_password by 'root';
```

Answer (score 2):

Well the easiest way to reset root password is:

- **restart mysqld  --skip-grant-tables option**. This enables anyone to
  connect without a password and with all privileges. Because this is
  insecure, you might want to use --skip-grant-tables in conjunction
  with --skip-networking to prevent remote clients from connecting.
- Connect to the mysqld server with this command:
- shell> mysql Issue the following statements in the mysql client.
  Replace the password with the password that you want to use.
- mysql> UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('MyNewPass')
         ->                   WHERE User='root'; mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
- Stop the server, then restart it normally (without the --skip-grant-tables and --skip-networking options).

**Source Mysql documentation and personal experience:**

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/resetting-permissions.html

Answer (score 2):

In my case:

- I set plugin authentication to "" (empty) and I can't run mysql server:

SOLUTION:

1. nano /etc/mysql/my.cnf
2. edit:

[mysqld]

skip-grant-tables

3. service mysql restart
4. mysql -u root
5. use mysql
6. UPDATE mysql.user SET plugin = 'mysql_native_password' WHERE User = 'root'
7. flush privileges

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the same issue by running Workbench as administrator.

...I guess it's because of restrictions on company computers, in my case...

Answer (score 1):

MySQL default password for root is assigned depending on the way you have installed MySQL.

If you have installed it from MySQL Yum repository, MySQL SUSE repository, or RPM packages directly downloaded from Oracle, you can obtain the password using following command:

```sh
sudo grep 'temporary password' /var/log/mysqld.log
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out the following steps to overcome this issue:

1. Open terminal / command prompt and navigate to the bin folder of the MySQL installation folder. Then run the command `mysqld --console`.
2. If you can see that line `171010 14:58:22 [Note] --secure-file-priv` is set to NULL. Operations related to importing and exporting data are disabled, after executing the above command from the command prompt.
3. Then you need to check that the `mysqld` is either blocked by the Windows Firewall or another program.
4. If it's blocked by Windows Firewall then need to unblock from it and save settings.
5. To unblock the `mysqld` or `mysql` application, follow the below steps:

   1. Go to command prompt and type `wf.msc` to open the firewall settings.
   2. Click on Allow an app or feature through Windows Firewall.
   3. Check the `mysqld` or `mysqld` instances are available in the list and check the checkbox for the domain, public and private and save the settings.
6. Return to the bin folder and try the command from step 1 again.
7. It should work fine and not show any errors.

It should be possible to run the MySQL console without any problems now!

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the same issue using next sql and restarting MySQL server:

```
update mysql.user set Select_priv='Y',Insert_priv='Y',Update_priv='Y',Delete_priv='Y',Create_priv='Y',Drop_priv='Y',Reload_priv='Y',Shutdown_priv='Y',Process_priv='Y',File_priv='Y',Grant_priv='Y',References_priv='Y',Index_priv='Y',Alter_priv='Y',Show_db_priv='Y',Super_priv='Y',Create_tmp_table_priv='Y',Lock_tables_priv='Y',Execute_priv='Y',Repl_slave_priv='Y',Repl_client_priv='Y',Create_view_priv='Y',Show_view_priv='Y',Create_routine_priv='Y',Alter_routine_priv='Y',Create_user_priv='Y',Event_priv='Y',Trigger_priv='Y',Create_tablespace_priv='Y'
where user='root';
```

Answer (score 0):

I worked on Access Denied for User 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) for several hours, I have found following solution,

```
The answer to this problem was that in the my.cnf located within
/etc/mysql/my.cnf

the line was either 
bind-address = 127.0.0.1 
            (or)
bind-address = localhost
            (or)
bind-address = 0.0.0.0

I should prefer that 127.0.0.1

I should also prefer 0.0.0.0, it is more flexible 
because which will allow all connections
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you have to escape the `--init-file` parameter:

`"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysqld.exe" --defaults-file="C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.6\\my.ini" --init-file=C:\\mysql-init.txt`

**Should be:**

`"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysqld.exe" --defaults-file="C:\\Program Files\\MySQL\\MySQL Server 5.6\\my.ini" --init-file=C:\mysql-init.txt`

Answer (score 0):

for the above problem ur password in the system should matches with the password u have passed in the program because when u run the program it checks system's password as u have given root as a user so gives u an error and at the same time the record is not deleted from the database.

```
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
class Delete
{
    public static void main(String []k)
    {
        String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/student";

        String user="root";
        String pass="jacob234";
        try
        {
            Connection myConnection=DriverManager.getConnection(url,user,pass);
            Statement myStatement=myConnection.createStatement();
            String deleteQuery="delete from students where id=2";
            myStatement.executeUpdate(deleteQuery);
            System.out.println("delete completed");
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Keep ur system password as jacob234 and then run the code.

Answer (score 0):

With me was the same problem, but it was caused, because i was using the mysql server on 32 (bit) and the workbench was running on 64(bit) version. the server and the workbench need to has the same version.

## xpress

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem when I'm trying to connecting Mysql database using the Laravel application. 
I would like to recommend please check the password for the user. MySQL password should not have special characters like **#**, **&**, etc...

Comment: On bluehost, removing special characters from the password actually fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

cause might be missing mysqld file in /var/run/mysqld

```
sudo service mysql stop
sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables
sudo service mysql start
```

if file does not exits then create file

```
mkdir -p /var/run/mysqld
chown mysql:mysql /var/run/mysqld
```

check now you are able to login mysql -uroot -p123
otherwise do

```
sudo mysql -u root
use mysql;
show tables;
describe user;
update user set authentication_string=password('1111') where user='root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
exit;
mysql -uroot -p123
```

link - [mysqld_safe Directory '/var/run/mysqld' for UNIX socket file don't exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42153059/mysqld-safe-directory-var-run-mysqld-for-unix-socket-file-dont-exists)

Answer (score 0):

**For windows:-**

If the instance configuration fails with similar issue and if you cannot log in to the root account.

[image]

**Steps I followed to fix the issue:**-

- Stop MySql service if running.
- Uninstall MySql using 'remove' option from the installation wizard.
- If MySql service is not removed from services,

> sc delete <MYSQL_SERVICE_NAME>

- Delete all data containing in the MySql folder ('Program files', 'Program data' or the custom installation directory you have given).
- Remove MySql path from the environmental variable.
- Disable windows firewall.
- *Reinstall and config root account with new password.*

Answer (score 0):

the only thing that worked was  `sudo mysql` followed by adding `skip-grant-tables` in [mysqld] section of /etc/my.cnf file - Ubuntu Mysql 5.5

Answer (score 0):

Please do crosscheck your password from your phpmyadmin login webpage on localhost, if its correct, then it will work without tempering with yoru credentials

Answer (score -2):

Same issue occurred with me also, turned out my db username was wrong