# MySQL - unable to grant root privileges: Access denied for user 'root'@'%' (using password: YES)

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to grant full privileges to the root user. Having tried via Workbench (Windows), this failed with the message:

```
Access denied for user 'root'@'%' (using password: YES)
```

Having researched the issue (trying fixes as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17975120/access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password-yes-no-privileges) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17975120/access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password-yes-no-privileges)), I have tried to resolve by granting root privileges via the command line, which fails with the same message.

[image]

If I try to grant privileges on 'root'@'localhost' instead, I get the same error, presumably because I am still trying to set through user 'root'@'%'?

[image]

The MySQL docs (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/access-denied.html) say

> If you get the following error, it means that you are using an incorrect root password:
>
> shell> mysqladmin -u root -pxxxx ver Access denied for user
>   'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

But I know the password is correct.

Security is not a major concern at the moment (running on a firewalled dev machine).

The result of `SHOW GRANTS FOR 'root'@'%';` is as follows:

```
Grants for root@%

GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, RELOAD, SHUTDOWN, PROCESS,
FILE, REFERENCES, INDEX, ALTER, SHOW DATABASES, SUPER, CREATE TEMPORARY 

TABLES,
LOCK TABLES, EXECUTE, REPLICATION SLAVE, REPLICATION CLIENT, CREATE VIEW, SHOW
VIEW, CREATE ROUTINE, ALTER ROUTINE, CREATE USER, TRIGGER, CREATE TABLESPACE ON
*.* TO 'root'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '<REMOVED>' |
| GRANT PROXY ON ''@'' TO 'root'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What happens if you use a machine name, rather than `'%'` (which will match to any machine name)?

Comment: I try to grant privileges on 'root'@'localhost' instead, I get the same error, presumably because I am still trying to set through user 'root'@'%'? (Post edited to show output)

Comment: What does this show you `show grants for 'root'@'%';`

Comment: I've updated the question to show the output of `show grants for 'root'@'%';`

Comment: Thats weird for me `show grants` shows me exactly your first query.One solution is to remove all grants and regrant them but if you remove the grants you might not be able to grant them back,so be careful.

Comment: Ended up reinstalling mysql, and copying the default mysql database over to the data directory.