# Reset Mysql workbench root password

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I messed up something and I try creating a local server in the mysql workbench but an error message show up every time I test the connection.

[image]

I tried uninstalling the mysql workbench and installing again but the for user "root" is unknown. It did not tell anything about the root password during the installation process and I tried various password like empty string, my mac password etc but none of them works, I try researching in stackoverflow but I still cannot solve it.

Comment: You must change something on the server side of MySQL, as MySQL workbench is just a client and has nothing to do with password setting.

Comment: How can I change it? In mac, under the preference, It just have the stop mysql server button?

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17975120/access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password-yes-no-privileges

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For MAC user / OSX user

Try the command `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` when you log into the MySQL terminal.
If that doesn't work, try the following set of commands while in the MySQL  terminal

```
$ mysql -u root
mysql> USE mysql;
mysql> UPDATE user SET password=PASSWORD("NEWPASSWORD") WHERE User='root';
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
mysql> quit
```

Change out `NEWPASSWORD` with whatever password you want. Should be all set!

`Update:` As of MySQL 5.7, the password field has been renamed `authentication_string`. When changing the password, use the following query to change the password. All other commands remain the same:

```
mysql> UPDATE user SET authentication_string=PASSWORD("NEWPASSWORD") WHERE User='root';
```

Comment: I got a error ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'password' in 'field list'

Comment: when executing the third line

Comment: let me know your mysql version

Comment: Server version: 5.7.11 MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Comment: instead of third line ,execute this.. UPDATE user SET authentication_string=PASSWORD("NEWPASSWORD") where User='root';

Comment: After using your code,     "     ->" shows up, but it did not work.

Comment: I appreciate your help though

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103559/discussion-between-user-and-kkkk).

Answer (score 1):

Mysql change forgotted password

```
0) shut down service mysql56

1) go to C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6
 (note that ProgramData is a hidden folder)

2) look for file my.ini, open it and add one line skip-grant-tables below [mysqld],
      save  [mysqld]

skip-grant-tables
3) start service mysql56

4) by right, you can access the database, and use the query below to update the password

update mysql.user set password=PASSWORD('NEW PASSWORD') where user='root';
5) shun down the service again, remove the line skip-grant-tables save it, and start the service again. try to use the password you set to login.
```