# What happen to phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I don't know what happen. I just set a password in one of accounts registered and that appears. What to do?

Error
MySQL said: Documentation

> 1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
>    mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
>    phpMyAdmin tried to connect to the MySQL server, and the server rejected the connection. You should check the host, username and password in your configuration and make sure that they correspond to the information given by the administrator of the MySQL server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access Denied for User 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) - No Privileges?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17975120/access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password-yes-no-privileges)

Comment: You have to update your new password in `config.inc.php` in the line `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'yourpassword';`

Answer (score 0):

```
$serverName = "localhost";
$myDb = "prodectDb";
$user = "root";
$password = "root";
// use your database password or default password root or check 
//password using empty


$con = mysqli_connect($serverName,$user,$password,$myDb);
```

Comment: Please add more details to your answer, for example the file that needs these changes.

Comment: your configuration file where you have given your server_name, db_name db_password, and db_username to connect with database