# I am getting error "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost" when trying to use Connector/Python

Tags: python, mysql, connector

I am trying to connect to my local mysql system using python.

I note that I can only login to my mysql system from the console by
sudo /usr/bin/mysql -u root -p

I have looked around the web and am very confused by all the suggestions of which none work for me.

Like I tried

```
mysql> SELECT User, Host, plugin FROM mysql.user;
```

Which gives me 
...

```
+------------------+-----------+-----------------------+
| User             | Host      | plugin                |
+------------------+-----------+-----------------------+
| root             | localhost | mysql_native_password |
| mysql.session    | localhost | mysql_native_password |
| mysql.sys        | localhost | mysql_native_password |
| debian-sys-maint | localhost | mysql_native_password |
| keith            | localhost | mysql_native_password |
+------------------+-----------+-----------------------+

5 rows in set (0.12 sec)
```

...

...

```
import mysql.connector

cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user='root', password='#########',
                          host='127.0.0.1',
                          database='SurveyData')
cnx.close()
```

...

I get the following errors

...

```
MySQLInterfaceError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
~/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mysql/connector  /connection_cext.py in _open_connection(self)
    199         try:
--> 200             self._cmysql.connect(**cnx_kwargs)
    201         except MySQLInterfaceError as exc:

MySQLInterfaceError: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
```

Comment: Please don't post passwords and have you tried creating a user with database specific privileges?

Answer (score 4):

Logging in with the root user can be considered a "petential risk" and this explains the blocking of any connection through this user. So the solution is to create a new user and grant them all privileges.

```
mysql> CREATE USER 'newuser'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'newpassword';    
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'newuser'@'localhost';
```

Answer (score 0):

It seemes that you use root@localhost then connecting. Have you tried root@127.0.0.1 ?

Also check out: [Access Denied for User 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) - No Privileges?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17975120/access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password-yes-no-privileges)

Grant Global Privileges To User Account By Command Line.
Open a terminal and run below command.

```
:~$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
mysql> GRANT SELECT ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

Grant Special Schema Privileges To User Account.
Open terminal run below command.

```
:~$ mysql -u root -p
Enter password: 
mysql> GRANT SELECT,UPDATE,INSERT,DELETE ON SurveyData.* TO 'root'@'localhost';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON SurveyData.* TO 'root'@'localhost';
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

I use this script for test:

```py
try:
    connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
                                         database='SurveyData',
                                         user='root',
                                         password='########')

    if connection.is_connected():
        db_Info = connection.get_server_info()
        print("Connected to MySQL Server version ", db_Info)
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute("select database();")
        record = cursor.fetchone()
        print("Your connected to database: ", record)

except Error as e:
    print("Error while connecting to MySQL", e)
finally:
    if (connection.is_connected()):
        cursor.close()
        connection.close()
        print("MySQL connection is closed")
```

Comment: I tried the following and am giving up trying to format, I put 4 spaces in each line but no deal.

mysql> GRANT SELECT ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
     Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

     mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON SurveyData.* TO 'root'@'localhost';
     Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

     mysql> GRANT SELECT,UPDATE,INSERT,DELETE ON SurveyData.* TO 'root'@'localhost';
     Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

     mysql> SHOW GRANTS FOR root
         -> ;
     ERROR 1141 (42000): There is no such grant defined for user 'root' on host '%'

Comment: Not sure what fixed things but now accessing ok via user keith

Comment: What OS version and SQL version are you running?