# Access denied in phpmyadmin with MySql

Tags: phpmyadmin

I can't login in phpmyadmin suddenly.

[image: in]

Comment: Have you made any recent changes to the password/permissions?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17975120/access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password-yes-no-privileges

Comment: @ceejayoz, I can't remember. Most probably no.

Comment: Can you connect from the command line client? If you've completely lost access, the MySQL manual has documentation on resetting your root password: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html