# How to install phpmyadmin in ubuntu ec2 instance

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, phpmyadmin

Hello I want `phpmyadmin` to work on my instance url (http://13.126.105.89/phpmyadmin) I am getting `404 not found error` on front page, but when I install phpmyadmin on ubuntu ec2 instance it is showing error. I have already installed apache and php and mysql-server but phpmyadmin is not getting started, how to make this work?. Below is the error shown when I try to install phpmyadmin:-

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree      
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package phpmyadmin
```

Comment: Have you updated packages beforeahand? `apt update -y`?

Comment: @Marcin I updated after installing apache and php, the I realized that I need to update it. After I update the packages, then I tried to install phpmyadmin. Phpmyadmin packages have been installed, now it is not working and also phpmyadmin.conf is not generated in  /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/.

Comment: Check this [url here](https://techpulsetoday.com/requested-url-phpmyadmin-not-found-server/)

Comment: @MayurFartade Thanks, it worked. Now the url is working. But when I try to login using credentials in phpmyadmin it is showing error "mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)"

Comment: Check your password, your password is wrong that's why you are getting this error.

Comment: @MayurFartade yes when i try to login mysql -u root -p and enter the password. It is showing error "access denied for user 'root@localhost' (using password: YES). How to resolve this?

Comment: Check this [click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17975120/access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password-yes-no-privileges). I hope this will resolve your issue

Comment: @MayurFartade thanks. It has worked :)