# Cannot access MySQL, it keeps returning different errors

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I keep running into the following error message when I try to access MySQL (8.0.25) using MyPhpAdmin on Mac.

```
mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/1045): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I've tried to follow different solutions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17975120/access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password-yes-no-privileges), but I'm running into different error messages. Not sure what to do. I even downgraded MySQL to no avail.

I read the manual but could not find much.

When I run

```
sudo /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql
```

I receive

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

When I run the following and typed the password

```
sudo /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -u root
```

I receive

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

When I run

```
sudo /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld --skip-grant-tables
```

I receive

```
[System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.25) starting as process 2733
2021-11-17T22:09:59.111529Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /usr/local/mysql-8.0.25-macos11-x86_64/data/ is case insensitive
2021-11-17T22:09:59.111580Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010123] [Server] Fatal error: Please read "Security" section of the manual to find out how to run mysqld as root!
2021-11-17T22:09:59.111630Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2021-11-17T22:09:59.111785Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.25)  MySQL Community Server - GPL.
```

It does not allow access regardless of how I try. Not sure where to go from here.

Comment: The first few errors are because you are not specifying a password. Use the `-p` argument to prompt for one. If you forgot the password, using `--skip-grant-tables` can help with that, but you have to run MySQL as the appropriate user, not `root`. (Probably the username is `mysql`)

Comment: Thanks @Evert I used -p and typed the password but it returned an error. sudo /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql -u root -p 
Password:
Enter password: 
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Comment: then you have the wrong password!