# Cannot connect to "@localhost". Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Tags: django

I try to connect mysql to django project
Here my settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'django_db',
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'root',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': 3306,
    }
```

}
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8iyK.png)

Comment: Please study [link](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct) about how to ask better question.

Comment: If you put your password blank it may be worked. **'PASSWORD': '  '**,

Comment: @NEBEZ I erased the password and left the form blank, It still doesn't work, Sorry, first time asking a question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17975120/access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password-yes-no-privileges

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you do not have such user in your database.
Please use that command in terminal, while being inside of your app's main folder:

```
python manage.py createsuperuser
```