# Unable to connect mysql with a new connection on mac

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-connector

The mac os is ventura 13.3
I installed mysql with brew and make sure that it run on port 3306. In system settings, the mysql(v8.0.33) is confirmed to be running.

The sequence of installation is first installing mysql with brew, and then downloading and installing workbench.

```
@XtekiMacBook-Pro:~|⇒  sudo lsof -i :3306

Password:
COMMAND PID   USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
mysqld  271 _mysql   20u  IPv6 0xf76932d83b2ef0a3      0t0  TCP *:mysql (LISTEN)
```

But not sure why, I cannot connect with any new mysql connection in mysql workbench. Everytime I click the 'Test Connection' button after setting username and password (stored in keychain), the test connection fails. I am confused because on windows I didn't experience this. Any advice is welcome.

[image]

Comment: It looks like you have issue with your credentials / privileges. Hoping this will helps you to resolve. [How to Solve MySQL Error: Access denied for user root@localhost](https://phoenixnap.com/kb/access-denied-for-user-root-localhost) , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17975120/access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password-yes-no-privileges

Comment: https://github.com/jadecubes/How-to-setup-nginx-mysql-php-environment