# Cannot connect to database MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have been trying to solve same problem for a couple of hours, searched for solution on the internet and I'm pretty sure I made some kind of mistake connecting to database, because whenever I try to send registration form I get this error:

> Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

I have included the file which is in the same folder as file that I'm using:

```
include_once("db_memberShip.php");
```

though,even if I try to use the "mysqli_connect("","","",""); without including the connection file I still get the same error.Any ideas?

Comment: What if you try to connect from the command line?  What is the output of `mysql -u root` ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Access denied for user 'root@localhost' (using password:NO)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2995054/access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-passwordno)

Comment: I'm pretty new to mysql and this is my first website that I'm trying to make, so where exactly should I use this mysql -u root? might look pretty stupid but I'm really new to this,though I'm learning fast :)

Comment: Not fast enough, it seems.