# JDBC Access denied error

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I am trying to deploy my application to another server, and while the JDBC connection worked in my machine, I couldn't get it to work with this mysql server.

Some information about the mysql server:

```
    select user(); 
    +----------------+
    | user()         |
    +----------------+
    | root@localhost |
    +----------------+

    mysql> show variables where Variable_name="port";
    +---------------+-------+
    | Variable_name | Value |
    +---------------+-------+
    | port          | 3306  |
    +---------------+-------+
```

There is no password to login into the mysql with user localhost (**mysql -u root** will be enough to login)

I used the following statement to connect to the database

```
    DriverManager.getConnection(
        "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database_name", "root", ""));
```

But, It throws the following error

```
     java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Uername or password or ipaddress(localhost) is wrong possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2995054/access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-passwordno

Comment: You should set the password of db user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting a password for `root` user. It is very bad and insecure to have `root` user without credentials. This [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/resetting-permissions.html) will help

Comment: Thanks for a quick response. But isn't there any way that I connect to mysql server, who don't have a password set? Did DriverManager.getConnection() method only works for password protected mysql servers?

Comment: The problem here is you actually have a password for `root`. But, you are trying to connect without the password. that's why i suggested you to reset the password.

Comment: But I am able login to the server without providing a password - mysql -u root

Comment: Try sending the password as `null`

Comment: Thanks all for the help. I mark this one as an answer 'cause I didn't try sending the password as null, as I set up a password for mysql before going through that, and think, perhaps, it might work with password set as null.

Answer (score 1):

you need to in **%MYSQL_INSTALL_PATH%/bin** folder,using cmd and run:

```
mysqld -nt --skip-grant-tables
mysqladmin -u root flush-privileges password "NEW_PASSWORD"
```

and **restart** mysql service.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `mysql -u root -p` , with the password field not provided?
I guess here's the problem
`"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database_name", "root", ""));` you used a `""` as your password so I think you need to do this `mysql -u root -p`

Comment: There is no password needed to login to mysql. Its not the one troubling me. My problem is I couldn't connect to a mysql server (one having no password) in JDBC.