# Web hosting - Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: php, mysql, web-hosting

I'm uploading my website on HostGator, but I have a problem with MySql, i get this error :

```
Access denied for user 'hostgatoruser'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

And this is my php code :

```
try
{
    $DB = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=hostgatoruser_database', 'hostgatoruser_abc', '********');
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
        die('Erreur : '.$e->getMessage());
}
```

Why the error tells me *Access denied for user "**hostgatoruser@localhost**"* instead of "**hostgatoruser_abc**" ? How to fix it ?

EDIT: OK, the problem was caused by the mysql_real_escape_string functions, so I removed them. I still dunno why I can't use mysql_real_escape_string...

Comment: It seems you don`t need a password to connect to the db (similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2995054/access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-passwordno)

Comment: but when I don't use the password, it says Access denied for user "hostgatoruser_abc@localhost" (using password: NO)

Comment: If it only gives you the first error when you use a password, check that your password doesn't have any characters that might cause problems. Single quotes, backslashes, etc.

Comment: My password uses six numbers only

Comment: Have you contacted hostgator's support?

Comment: @user3620454: Glad you resolved your issue. `mysql_real_escape` does not work with PDO because they do not know of each other and do not share credentials. If you want to know more, you should ask a specific question.

Comment: So, I searched on the net, and with the PDO class I only need to use prepared statements to protect my database

Comment: As I can see on the net, I don't need to use

Answer (score 0):

As well as some of the comments here suggesting you check your username/password, it's also worth checking that the user has got permissions granted for that particular database.

You can find out what permissions you've been given by running:

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR 'hostgatoruser'@'localhost';
```

Comment: There were just a conflict with mysql_real_escape();