# Access denied for 'root'@'localhost' using Password=YES

Tags: java, mysql

I am trying to log into mysql though java with a .jar file I am running on the server. And here is my code, but I keep coming up with this error

```
Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

I have read a bunch of answers for this on SO and such but nothing has worked for me. I am trying to log in as root on the localhost. Here is code

```
String myDriver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
      String myUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/db";
      Class.forName(myDriver);
      Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(myUrl, "root", "myPassword");
```

I have tried this

```
mysql -uroot
```

But then get `Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)` but when I run the .jar file I get `Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)`

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2995054/access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-passwordno

Comment: @utility I have tried that its not working

Comment: @spen123 What means 'all this'? `--skip-grant-tables` always works. With this option (on mysql**d**) you are able to login with and without password. Then you have a chance to fix your permissions table