# Symfony3 The server returned a "500 Internal Server Error"

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, symfony-3.1

I wanted to put my symfony3 code to hosting and after all i got

> Oops! An Error Occurred
>
> The server returned a "500 Internal Server Error".
>
> Something is broken. Please let us know what you were doing when this
>   error occurred. We will fix it as soon as possible. Sorry for any
>   inconvenience caused.

my parameters.yml

# This file is auto-generated during the composer install

parameters:

```
database_host: db.if.ktu.lt
database_port: null
database_name: lukmil
database_user: lukmil
database_password: "MyPassword"
mailer_transport: smtp
mailer_host:       127.0.0.1
mailer_user:       ~
mailer_password:   ~
secret: ThisTokenIsNotSoSecretChangeIt
```

that's what i get from prod log

> [2016-10-11 18:18:40] request.INFO: Matched route "{route}".
>   {"route":"authentication_register","route_parameters":{"_controller":"AppBundle\Controller\DefaultController::indexAction","_route":"authentication_register"},"request_uri":"http://lukmil.stud.if.ktu.lt/register","method":"GET"}
>   [] [2016-10-11 18:18:40] security.INFO: Populated the TokenStorage
>   with an anonymous Token. [] [] [2016-10-11 18:18:40] request.CRITICAL:
>   Uncaught PHP Exception Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ConnectionException:
>   "An exception occured in driver: SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied
>   for user 'root'@'stud.if.ktu.lt' (using password: NO)" at
>   /home/lukmil/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/AbstractMySQLDriver.php
>   line 103 {"exception":"[object]
>   (Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ConnectionException(code: 0): An exception
>   occured in driver: SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user
>   'root'@'stud.if.ktu.lt' (using password: NO) at
>   /home/lukmil/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/AbstractMySQLDriver.php:103,
>   Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOException(code: 1045): SQLSTATE[28000]
>   [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'stud.if.ktu.lt' (using password:
>   NO) at
>   /home/lukmil/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:47,
>   PDOException(code: 1045): SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for
>   user 'root'@'stud.if.ktu.lt' (using password: NO) at
>   /home/lukmil/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:43)"}
>   []

What could I do?
On localhost it worked.. just in hosting doesn't

Comment: Never share the password. I edited twice to hide the password

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ok, I found a fix.. I downloaded putty program then logged in and use php bin/console cache:clear --env=prod
 with clearing the cache my problem solved :)

Comment: you save my day

Answer (score 1):

```
$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', true);
```

in path `/web/app.php`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your database credentials for your server are correctly added to your configuration file (.yml) and that your database user has the permissions to access the database your attempting to access.

Good practice would be to create a user with access to the respective database only as using root shouldn't be used directly.

Comment: it's a university hosting.. so i have only one user.. before symfony I could access database normally

Answer (score 0):

You are using root without a password. Please don't.

Check this [Access denied for user 'root@localhost' (using password:NO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2995054/access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-passwordno)

And create a user to access the database, try not to use the root user.

Remove the " from the password

The parameters should be like this:

```
database_port: null
database_name: lukmil
database_user: lukmil
database_password: MyPassword
```

Comment: ok there was mysql -u root password '123' but where i should do these commands in mysql ?

Comment: @lukmil Remove the "" from the password string. Symfony is reading the entire string, including the "

Answer (score 0):

Is important check the twice enviroments. 
For example in my case my code is perfect in dev: 
app_dev.php/web/login

but in production:
/web/login

I have this error: “500 Internal Server Error”

Then I checked the log of production and finded the error.

Maybe is help you too.

Regards