# Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO) with MySQL in JavaFX

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

Im using my root account to login to mysql from a javafx app but im denied with 
 Acces Denied ''@'localhost' (using password: NO).
This is my code:

```
    public void ConnnectClicked(ActionEvent e) throws SQLException {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error: unable to load driver class!");
        System.exit(1);
    }
    String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/world";
    String name = username.getSelectedText();
    String pass = password.getSelectedText();

    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, name, pass);
    primaryStage.setScene(country);
}
```

As you can see its just a basic connection scheme in javafx. Doenst "password no" means theres something worng with my user account?

Comment: if you print out name and pass on the console, is it what you expect to see?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2995054/access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-passwordno

Comment: I cant get anything to print.

Comment: I get no error when manually putting in the pass and name. Im guessing its a problem with my textfields not passing their strings. Thanks for the help anyway. Ill continue to work on my textfields to see what going on.

Comment: The error indicates that `name` and `pass` were empty. Maybe you don't want `getSelectedText`, but `getText` (or something similar) instead.

Comment: Figured it out. I needed to use getText() instead of getSelectedText(). Im a bit rusty so thanks for putting up with me.

Answer (score 3):

It's just a guess, but if those are text boxes:

```
String name = username.getSelectedText();
String pass = password.getSelectedText();
```

Then you should propably use username.getText(), because selectedText is the text you marked with your mouse. If you didnt mark it (blue highlighting), then it's empty.