# Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' but works locally

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, mariadb, mariasql

I'm trying to deploy my cakephp project on my virtual machine.

When I type `mysql -u root -p` on my VM it  works but cakephp seems to not have access to this.

Here is how my DB config looks like:

```
'Datasources' => [
    'default' => [
        'className' => 'Cake\Database\Connection',
        'driver' => 'Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => '127.0.0.1',
        //'port' => 'non_standard_port_number',
        'username' => 'root',
        'password' => '',
        'database' => 'webarena',
        'encoding' => 'utf8',
        'timezone' => 'UTC',
        'flags' => [],
        'cacheMetadata' => true,
        'log' => false,
        'quoteIdentifiers' => false,
        'url' => env('DATABASE_URL', null),
    ],
```

And I've got the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1698] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
```

So I tried to set a new password by doing so:

```
mysql> UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('SecurePassword') WHERE
User='root';
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
mysql> EXIT
```

But still doesn't work.

I can also type `mysql` and it works? How's that possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access denied for user 'root@localhost' (using password:NO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2995054/access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-passwordno)

Answer (score 0):

Your Question is unclear, especially the title word "locally".  My Answer follows one interpretation; BenRoob's "dup of" follows another.

"localhost" is a different "host" from those with an IP address or host name.  The `GRANT` tables make a distinction.  I think you are tripping over such.

```
    GRANT ... to 'user'@'localhost' ...
```

lets `user` get in when running from the *same* machine.  `'127.0.0.1'` and `'::`' are probably synonyms for `'localhost'`.

```
    GRANT ... to 'user'@'%' ...
```

lets `user` get in from any *other* machine.  (For security reasons, '%' is not advised.)