# Python connect Mysql

Tags: python, mysql

i want to use cmd python to connect mysql database, but it not working and show me the error. After several try, still can't figure out how to fix this problem
can someone help me?
thanks

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access denied for user 'root@localhost' (using password:NO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2995054/access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-passwordno)

Comment: For starters: edit your post and replace screenshot with text and format as code (look at tools panel). Next: prove that you are sure that mysql database alive and kicking: connectable by other clients

Comment: sry , this is my first time to use this platform to ask question. thanks your suggest, i will try on next time !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the 3d param is password. you set in code "root". check  the real pass.
or if you don't have a passwd try this:

```
conn = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', port=3306, user='root', passwd='', db='mysql')
```

or as like [here](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/blob/master/example.py) or [here](http://pymysql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/examples.html) or [here](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL)