# Output keeps saying: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: javascript, netbeans, xampp

I'm trying to connect my login system in Netbeans JAVA to my SQL database but it keeps on saying in the output 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'

I'm not using a password for the root@localhost and I've added 'skip-grant-tables' in my.cnf file but it still doesn't allow me to connect

**This is my connection:**

```
    public static Connection getConnection() {
        Connection con = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            con = (Connection)               
        DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/exam_provision?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&useSSL=false", "root", "");
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex.getMessage());
        }
        return con;
    }
```

It just gives me this:

Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at examprovisionassistant.gui.RegisterScreen.submitButtonMouseClicked(RegisterScreen.java:221)
    at examprovisionassistant.gui.RegisterScreen.access$200(RegisterScreen.java:21)
    at examprovisionassistant.gui.RegisterScreen$3.mouseClicked(RegisterScreen.java:94)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseClicked(AWTEventMulticaster.java:270)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6542)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3324)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6304)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2239)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4889)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2297)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4904)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4544)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4476)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2283)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2746)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4711)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:760)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:84)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:733)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:731)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:74)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:730)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:205)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)

Comment: I thought that error message was a MySQL one; are you really using Microsoft sql server like you've indicated in the tags? If MySQL, have you seen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2995054/access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-passwordno?

Comment: Woops I tagged the wrong thing. I'm using XAMPP.

Comment: It's be worth adding the MySQL tag as XAMPP is a suite of software but this problem is specific to only the MySQL component