# Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO) in Eclipse, instead of 'root'@'localhost', classpath corrupted

Tags: java, mysql, sql, eclipse

I'm making a java project with SceneBuilder and Eclipse; i need to connect to a local database created using MySQL, but after running my Java code in eclipse i get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:836)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:456)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:246)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:197)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.admin.TimezoneDump.main(TimezoneDump.java:70)
```

Instead of `'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)` that is a login credentials error, now i have `''@'localhost' (using password: NO)`.
Using MySQL workbench and command prompt, i can correctly access using "root"/"root", and launch queries on my db. Running the same Eclipseproject on another laptop or my home pc, i can run it without errors. So the problem is not in the code but in some setting of my current laptop.

I already tried to:

- Uninstall and reinstall Eclipse.
- Uninstall and reinstall mySQL products: Workbench, Server, J Connector.
- Switch Eclipse workspace.
- Open the 3306 port from windows firewall.

That's the part of the code where i try to connect to my db.

```
package model;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;



public class UserDAO {

    private static String USER = "root";
    private static String PASS = "root";
    private static String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://127.0.0.1:3306/beecological?useUnicode=true&useJDBCCompliantTimezoneShift=true&useLegacyDatetimeCode=false&serverTimezone=UTC";
    private static String DRIVER_CLASS_NAME = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver";


    public static boolean checkUsername(String username) {
        Statement stmt = null;
        Connection conn = null;
        int res = 1;

        try {

            Class.forName(DRIVER_CLASS_NAME);

            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);

            stmt = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
                    ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
            res = Queries.verifyUsernameAvailable(stmt, username);

            stmt.close();
            conn.close();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if(res == 1) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static void saveUser(User instance) {
        Statement stmt = null;
        Connection conn = null;

        try {

            Class.forName(DRIVER_CLASS_NAME);

            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);

            stmt = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
                    ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
            Queries.insertUser(stmt, instance);

            stmt.close();
            conn.close();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static boolean verifyLogin(User instance) {
        Statement stmt = null;
        Connection conn = null;
        int res = 0;

        try {
            //caricamento driver mysql
            Class.forName(DRIVER_CLASS_NAME);

            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);

            stmt = conn.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE,
                    ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
            res = Queries.verifyUserRegistered(stmt, instance);

            stmt.close();
            conn.close();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        if (res == 0) {
            return false;   //utente immesso non esiste
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Access denied for user 'root@localhost' (using password:NO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2995054/access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-passwordno)

Comment: Maybe, your empty user is the problem, see the error message `...: Access denied for user ''@'localhost' (using password: NO)`, it has an empty `String` as user name, doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, that's the problem, but i don't know how this is possible, because using workbench i access the database correctly using user: 'root' and psw: 'root'

Comment: If you have enabled `using password: NO`, you don't have to provide a password, but it is not recommended to use the root without a password. Anyway, it is weird the username is emptied somehow... You can try it without password, but I doubt it will change this behaviour.

Comment: `using password: NO` it's an error, i access the db correctly using cmd and workbench using root/root. I get the error also if i remove completely from my code the `DriverManager.getConnection()`.

Comment: This `using password NO` looks like an option enabled... The error is `Access denied` for the empty username. At least the JDBC driver message appears like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### **Solution**

The problem was not about MySQL login credentials, but on Eclipse configuration.

In my folder project the `.classpath` and the `.project` files were corrupted. Infact going to `myproject>right click>Run As..>Run Configurations` the main class was setted as `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.admin.TimezoneDump.main` instead of my `mainApp` class. Trying to change there the main class file not worked, because for Eclipse the `mainApp` doesn't exist.

**So this is what i've done to solve the error:**

1. Delete the project from Eclipse (not on the disk)
2. Close Eclipse
3. Go to Project folder and delete `.classpath` and `.project` files
4. Open eclipse, go to  `File > Open projects from File System` and choose the project directory
5. Right click on the project > Run As > Run Configurations and set the right Main class