# Unable to analyse MySQL error logs in OSSEC

Tags: mysql, error-log, ossec, wazuh

I am trying to analyze MySQL error logs that are generated on my OSSEC agent and raise alerts using OSSEC server.

here is the code block added to /var/ossec/etc/ossec.conf on the agent side to read the error logs of MySQL from the agent:

```
  <localfile>
    <log_format>mysql_log</log_format>
    <location>/var/log/mysql/error.log</location>
  </localfile>
```

After doing so I have restarted the agent and server but unable test any error logs that are getting generated on the agent side like:

```
2020-09-15T04:09:24.164859Z 12 [Note] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

As per doc https://ossec-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/programs/ossec-logtest.html under **Caveats** we need to add MySQL log: to the log generated for the ossec-logtest.

This will be added automatically when we send these logs to the OSSEC server for analysis from the agent.

[ossec-logtest result for MySQL error log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/irjz4.png)

ossec-logtest is working fine after adding MySQL log: to the beginning but they are not working in the realtime.

Can anyone please help me through this problem.

Comment: I think you may need to provide a root password

Comment: @Code the issue is not with the mysql password. The issue is with ossec which is unable to analyze the MySQL logs which are generated on the ossec agent.

Comment: I think this may help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2995054/access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-passwordno

Answer (score 0):

The fact that ossec-logtest trigger an alert means that mysql decoder and rules are working fine

Check on Agent

- MySql is running. `systemctl status mysqld.service`
- MySql configuration (loglevel and output file) allow to log that kind of event . See [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_log-warnings)

> If the value is greater than 1, aborted connections are written to the
> error log, and access-denied errors for new connection attempts are
> written.

- MySql is effectively logging 'Access denied': `grep "Access denied" /var/log/mysql/error.log`
- Ossec and their processes is running ok: `/var/ossec/bin/ossec-control status`

Check on Manager

- `log_alert_level` field in /var/ossec/etc/ossec.conf is lower o equal than 9 (loglevel showed in your ossec-logtest)

Comment: Hi Juan, I got your point but the main issue is the logs are not reaching on the server-side while using the mysql_log format in the ossec.conf file. Therefore it is unable to analyze in the real time. Do you have any idea regarding it?

Comment: It's a long journey from generating logs to seeing the alert in the manager, where each step can be a filter that blocks the flow of data. What behavior indicates the is a server-side issue? I suggest you start the analysis of the problem starting from the agent.