# Can't connect MySQL to my spring boot project (java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost')

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-jdbc, mysql-connector, sqlexception

This is my 'application.properties' file

```
spring.jpa.open-in-view=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update


spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/abbc
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
```

when i running the project on ubuntu os it gives following error.

```
ERROR 11884 --- [         task-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool        : HikariPool-3 - Exception during pool initialization.

java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar:8.0.22]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar:8.0.22]
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:122) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.22.jar:8.0.22]
```

how i solve this problem?

Comment: also password is empty

Comment: grant privilidge of db to the user
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2995054/access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-passwordno