# MySQL Database doesn't run - XAMPP 8.1.6-0 MacOS M1

Tags: mysql, macos, xampp

I have just installed XAMPP, and I cannot run MySQL Database on Mac OS M1.
I have tried multiple things I have found online so far. First, I downloaded the 8.1.6 / PHP 8.1.6 (361 Mb) and I couldn't even start it, then I downloaded the 163 Mb version and everything seemed fine, except that I cannot run the database.
I have tried everything from [here](https://www.panayiotisgeorgiou.net/mysql-database-wont-start-in-xampp-manager-osx/), but it didn't work.
I couldn't find the ID either, after running

```
ps aux | grep mysql
```

I got:

```
_mysql           22508   0.0  1.1 34989944 178672   ??  Ss    3:39PM   0:00.30 /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld --user=_mysql --basedir=/usr/local/mysql --datadir=/usr/local/mysql/data --plugin-dir=/usr/local/mysql/lib/plugin --log-error=/usr/local/mysql/data/mysqld.local.err --pid-file=/usr/local/mysql/data/mysqld.local.pid --keyring-file-data=/usr/local/mysql/keyring/keyring --early-plugin-load=keyring_file=keyring_file.so
root             23300   0.0  0.0 408628368   1648 s000  S+    3:41PM   0:00.00 grep mysql
sh-3.2#
```

Server events:

```
Starting Apache Web Server...
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/apache2/scripts/ctl.sh : httpd started
Starting ProFTPD...
Checking syntax of configuration file
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/proftpd/scripts/ctl.sh : proftpd started
Stopping all servers...
Stopping Apache Web Server...
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/apache2/scripts/ctl.sh : httpd stopped
Stopping ProFTPD...
Checking syntax of configuration file
/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/proftpd/scripts/ctl.sh : proftpd stopped
```

Could someone help me with this, please?
Thank you.

Comment: you can try downgrading your PHP version. For example to 7.4

Comment: @MahmutSalman the installed php version has nothing to do with whether the mysql server will start up or not. PHP does not control mysql. I can't understand by what logic / information you made that suggestion?

Comment: And the logs are not about mysql, but about http and ftp services.

Comment: Can you provide relevant lines from the `/usr/local/mysql/data/mysqld.local.err` file?

Comment: @JamesRisner I can't open the file, it says that there is no application set to open it, and when I try again it shows me that I don't have permission to open it (I tried to change it from ```get info -> sharing & permissions: everyone - Read & Write``` , but it didn't work)

Comment: open Terminal.app then type `cat /usr/local/mysql/data/mysqld.local.err`, from there you can scroll through looking for lines with time stamps around where you had the issue.

Comment: @JamesRisner I get ```cat: /usr/local/mysql/data/mysqld.local.err: Permission denied```

Comment: open /usr/local in finder, then right click on mysql -> get info. At bottom for sharing permissions, unlock and add read/write for your user.

Comment: @JamesRisner it finally worked, I got a really long list: ```Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M```, ```Failed to set up SSL because of the following SSL library error: SSL context is not usable without certificate and private key```, ```Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled```. At the end: ```Version: '5.7.21'  socket: '/tmp/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)```
and then a long list of ```2022-09-15T10:14:20.232718Z 2 [Note] Access denied for user 'user'@'localhost' (using password: NO)```. I am not sure what this means.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2995054/access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-passwordno